# Include external eclipse project in maven generated war as jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have an eclipse project which has a reference to another project.
I've included this other project in the "Properties"->"Java Build Path" and in "Properties"->"Deployment Assembly" for the deployment on a server defined in eclipse workspace.
This configuration includes a jar of the external project in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Now I want generate a war file with the (right click) "Run As"->"Maven install" command.
I've added the maven-war-plugin plugin in the pom:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</webappDirectory>
        <warName>${project.artifactId}_${noVer}</warName>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries/>
            <manifestFile/>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is it possible to include the other project as a jar (automatically) in the war?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The "other project" is an eclipse project in the same workspace.
Actually is a maven jar project.
It's included in the original project as described before.
What I want to know is:
Is there a way (plugin, directive...) to include this ECLIPSE project directly in the pom of original project?
something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>other_eclipse_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

and then find a "other_eclipse_project.jar" in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1):

Ulrich's answer is correct, but it will only add the jar generated by the other project into your war.  If your other project depends on other jars, they won't be included.

I would be tempted to change the other project to a maven project and add all its dependencies to its pom, that way you will get all the transitive dependencies.

Comment: I agree. When I wrote my answer it seemed clear for me that there ist only one external library ("other project") which doesn't exist as maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you install the jar file of the "other project" in your local maven repository. To do this, use the maven install plugin. There are some variants:

1. create a `pom.xml` for "other project" and call `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>`. In the POM for "other project", specify its dependencies.
2. specify the maven coordinates as parameters: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar`

When you chose variant 2, you can't (AFAIK) specify dependencies of "other project".

When you've done this, you can add a dependency to "other project" in your maven project.

See also [Install non-maven artifact in local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you mean is that eclipse has the ability to fetch a maven dependency direct from workspace. This featuare is called "Workspace Resolution". Open the context menu on "MyApp", and in "Maven" you can activate workspace resolution. In eclipse Mars, it's disabled by default (AFAIK).

[image]